# Shouldn't $t^n : \mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ ramifies at $0$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Yo, this is probably the stupidest question ever that I've asked here.

Let $$\varphi: \mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$$ be the map of schemes (over a field $k$) such that $\varphi (x) = x^n$. In other words, $$\varphi^{\#}: k[t] \rightarrow k[t]$$ satisfies $\varphi^{\#} (t) = t^n$. Intuitively this should be the most stupid map that is unramified everywhere except at $0$. Let $(t)$ be the point zero. Localization at $(t)$ inverts every polynomial with an invertible constant term and quotienting by $k[t]_{(t)}(t)$ kills every higher term, remaining just the constant term. So at the level of residue fields $$\varphi^{\#}_{(t)}: k \rightarrow k$$ is the identity, which is certainly separable.

More generally, apparently, if $\varphi: X \rightarrow X$ is a map of $S$-schemes such that it fixes a point $x \in X$, then pointwise $\varphi_x : \kappa (x) \rightarrow \kappa (x)$ is always separable.

Certainly I'm committing a terribly stupid mistake. What's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your definition of ramification seems to have a bug. It should involve the induced map on local rings, not just residue fields. See for example p.299 of Hartshorne.

Comment: @Nefertiti I'm using the regular definition (EGA IV for instance): locally of finite presentation such that the morphism induced on residue fields is finite and separable. Your definition (this is just the usual ramification of function fields extensions ) is equivalent to mine for smooth curves and makes my map ramified at $0$. However I cannot find the problem.

Comment: @Hoot: This map for $n>1$ is _the_ local model for ramification.

Comment: @KReiser Quite right. I had it in my head that this thing was étale, completely forgetting the geometry (or any other senses, really).

Comment: The bug seems to be in this "morphism induced on residue fields" part. Of course there is always an induced map on residue fields, but the definition of unramified requires more.

Comment: @Nefertiti Sure, you're right. I'm so dumb. The uniformizer must go to the uniformizer or, more generally in higher Krull dimensions, the maximal ideal must go exactly to the maximal ideal.

Comment: @KReiser I believe it's the local model only for the smooth case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's run through this situation according to the map on local rings and we'll see where things differ from your argument.

Name the first $\mathbb{A}^1$ $X$ and the second one $Y$, so that our map is $\varphi:X\to Y$. The corresponding map on local rings is $\varphi^\#: \mathcal{O}_{Y,\varphi(x)}\to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. Let $\mathfrak{m}\subset \mathcal{O}_{Y,\varphi(x)}$ be the maximal ideal, and let $\mathfrak{n}=\varphi^\#(\mathfrak{m})\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, the ideal generated by the image of of $\mathfrak{m}$ in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

The map is unramified if it's locally of finite type and if for all $y\in Y$, $\mathfrak{n}$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and the obvious map $\mathcal{O}_{Y,\varphi(x)}/\mathfrak{m} \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{n}$ is a finite separable field extension.

The map is clearly locally of finite type. 1/3 so far.

Let's check whether $\mathfrak{n}$ is the maximal ideal: $\mathfrak{m}$ is principal and generated by $t$, so $\varphi^\#(\mathfrak{m})\mathcal{O}_{X,x}=\varphi^\#((t))k[t]_{(t)}=\varphi^\#(t)k[t]_{(t)}=(t^n)k[t]_{(t)}=(t^n)$ which is not maximal. Failure!

Your argument would be fine if you had some sort of guarantee that $\mathfrak{n}$ was maximal, but you do not. Your computation only holds for the case that $\mathfrak{n}$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have never noticed this condition even after proving a lot of things using this property. Now I wonder why the separability is even necessary...

Comment: @user40276 The other characterizations given in EGA might seem more natural. Certainly $(\Omega_{X/Y})_x = 0$ looks like an interesting condition.

Comment: @user40276: separability is important in situations over fields of positive characteristic. An inseparable extension is something like ramification- you expect there to be the correct number of points lying above something and there aren't, there's less than what you want.

Comment: @Hoot Yes,I know. But I'm trying to think about something more geometric. For instance using curves over finite fields, where just separability fails.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism locally of finite type. Then we say that $f$ is unramified at $x$ iff $$\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_{f(x)}\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$$
is a finite separable extension of $k(f(x))$.

So your argument is wrong, due to incorrect definition, what was already pointed out in comments. Assuming your "definition" of unramified morphism you can for example "prove" that any quasi-finite morphism of schemes which are locally of finite type over a field of characteristic zero is unramified, because for such morphisms:
$$k(f(x)))\rightarrow k(x)$$ 
is always finite and separable(characteristic zero).

Consider your map:
$$\phi:k[t]\rightarrow k[x]$$
given by $$\phi(t)=x^n$$
Then morphism induced on local rings:
$$k[t]_{(t)}\rightarrow k[x]_{(x)}$$
sends:
$$\frac{t}{1}\mapsto \frac{x^n}{1}$$
So in this case you derive:
$$k[x]_{(x)}/x^nk[x]_{(x)}\cong k[x]/(x^n)$$
which is not even a field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I don't understand your last isomorphism. Given a morphism of local rings, there's always a morphism on the residue fields. Maybe you mean that the image of the maximal is not maximal. Still I wonder why separability is important...